# Prove $\vdash \neg \neg A \leftrightarrow A$ in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

I want to prove $\vdash \neg \neg A \leftrightarrow A$ without using $RAA$ and $\bot$ rules. the part that $\vdash A \to \neg \neg A$ is simple but I can't prove the other part. is there any possibility for proving $\vdash \neg \neg A \to A$ without using $RAA$ and $\bot$ rule in natural deduction?

Comment: You cannot prove the "other part" because it is not intuitionistically valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you

Comment: See [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) for the basic facts about it.